# App restarts due to TMTimeFilter iOS8

Tags: uiwebview, ios8

When I start using my application (UIWebView - Hybrid app in iOS8.x), app restarts suddenly while i am in the middle of the app. When I look into the logs, I got the below line while app restarts point.

**CoreTime: Setting system time to 2015-04-13 10:32:40 +0000 from TMTimeFilter**

I do not know what it is exactly and how to fix this. Any help could be appreciated.